# Fiori wrong Routing. It goes to other View/Target

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm working with an old version of SAP Fiori (1.60.38).

I'm able to have two different views and go from one to another like:

Worklist.view.xml --> Detail.view.xml

Worklist.view.xml <-- Detail.view.xml

The problem now is because I have another view called "Finalizados" and I need to go from Worklist to this new view only when exist a condition. Even if I'm checking the condition and writing the navTo("Finalizados") it ended up in my Detail.controller.js and "finalizados" is as parameter.

Here is the manifest.json

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "com.ui5.apps.fg_recepciones.view",
            "controlId": "app",
            "controlAggregation": "pages",
            "bypassed": {
                "target": [
                    "notFound"
                ]
            },
            "async": true
        },
        "routes": [
            {
                "pattern": "",
                "name": "worklist",
                "target": [
                    "worklist"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "detail/{objectId}|{idExterno}|{tipo}|{Entrega}",
                "name": "detail",
                "target": [
                    "detail"
                ]
            },
            {
                "pattern": "finalizados/{objectId}|{idExterno}|{tipo}|{Entrega}",
                "name": "finalizados",
                "target": [
                    "finalizados"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "targets": {
            "worklist": {
                "viewName": "Worklist",
                "viewId": "worklist",
                "title": "{i18n>worklistViewTitle}",
                "viewLevel": 1
            },
            "detail": {
                "viewName": "Detail",
                "viewId": "detail",
                "title": "{i18n>objectViewTitle}",
                "viewLevel": 2
            },
            "finalizados": {
                "viewName": "Finalizados",
                "viewId": "finalizados",
                "title": "Finalizados",
                "viewLevel": 2
            },
            "objectNotFound": {
                "viewName": "ObjectNotFound",
                "viewId": "objectNotFound"
            },
            "notFound": {
                "viewName": "NotFound",
                "viewId": "notFound"
            }
        }
    },
```

Worklist.controller.js

```
        if (clase === "Recepcionados") {
            var destiny = "finalizados";
        } else {
            destiny = "detail";

        }

        tipo = tipo + clase;
        this.getRouter().navTo(destiny, {
            objectId: item.Pedido,
            tipo: tipo,
            idExterno: idExterno,
            Entrega: entrega
        });
```

What I receive in the attached PatternMatched from Detail.controller.js:

[image]

I'm supposed to receive everything with parameters in the Finalizados.controller.js. Can someone find what's going on here?

Comment: You say you are landing in detail.controller. Does it display the right view but load the wrong controller? Did you accidentally connect the wrong view with the wrong controller? And how do you initialize the attachpatternmatched?

Comment: Hi @Marc, yes. It loads the View and Controller from Detail, the hash is from "/Finalizados/..." and this is how I initialize the attachpatternmatched:

This is in Detail.controller.js:
this.getRouter().getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);

And this is in Finalizados.controller.js:
this.getRouter().getRoute("finalizados").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);

Comment: Its difficult to answer this with only this much code. However can you try following and let me know what you see in the debugger for both the controllers (_Detail_ & _Finalizados_) after **navTo** (from _Worklist_ controller).

**Detail.controller.js**

`onInit: function () {`
   `this.getRouter().getRoute("detail").attachRouteMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);`
`}`


**Finalizados.controller.js**

`onInit: function () {`
   `this.getRouter().getRoute("finalizados").attachRouteMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);`
`}`

Comment: Apart from this, you can also try adding **greedy** property to _finalizados_ route config in _manifest.json_

Another thing that I am unable to understand is the symbol **|** in your route patterns `finalizados/{objectId}|{idExterno}|{tipo}|{Entrega}`. Shouldn't it be something like this `finalizados/{objectId}/{idExterno}/{tipo}/{Entrega}`

Comment: Hi @codeartist, the | is used to separate all the parameters as an only one parameter with all together so we can split everything in the controller later.
When we navigate to Detail.controller.js we receive everything in parameters: objectId, idEsterno, tipo and also Entrega. We are not able to get to Finalizados.controller.js, that's the specific problem we are facing in this question.

Comment: Hi @CristianLópezGonzález, Apologies for the delayed response. Somehow, I didn't get any notification and had to come back to the question to find your reply.

I see you got the solution, Good to know that. Cheers (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the answer or workaround was just the order of the routes in the manifest.json.
Previously was defined as:

```
        {
            "pattern": "detail/{objectId}|{idExterno}|{tipo}|{Entrega}",
            "name": "detail",
            "target": [
                "detail"
            ]
        },
        {
            "pattern": "finalizados/{objectId}|{idExterno}|{tipo}|{Entrega}",
            "name": "finalizados",
            "target": [
                "finalizados"
            ]
        }
```

if we swap this order it works. We don't know exactly why but that's how we solved it.